# Is it possible and if so how do you hard reset a Boss DSD-2 guitar pedal?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal, delay

I was gifted the pedal and it was from a guitar store but stopped working after 20 minutes or so when I came back to play it for a second session. I’ve troubleshooted the power supply method with different supply cables and with batteries so the store suggested trying a factory reset. Is this possible for the DSD - 2?

Comment: I checked the [DSD-2 manual](https://www.synthxl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Boss-DSD-2-owner-manual.pdf) as well as the [DD-2 manual](http://cdn.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/DD-2_OM.pdf)...

Comment: ...([they share the same chip](https://reverb.com/item/44358032-boss-dsd-2-digital-delay-sampler-w-original-box-vintage-1985-made-in-japan-fast-shipping-br96?bk=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJiZjkyZmExZS1jOGQ2LTQ0NWYtYjBlYi02ZWY0M2IyMTk1N2MiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDE2MjQzOTIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIiLCJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjoiIiwiY29va2llX2lkIjoiM2FjMjZmZGEtYmJmMi00ZjQ3LWE2ODMtYTAxMWJlMGM0ZTc2IiwicHJvZHVjdF9pZCI6IjQ0MzU4MDMyIiwic291cmNlIjoiTk9ORSJ9.6KIsPkJzQuzLB3Psl9xktPfqt0qKQbAFhWUQyHzTaAo)) and found no indication of a way to perform a reset.

Comment: This [repair blog](http://falseelectronics.blogspot.com/2017/08/boss-dd-2.html) may be of interest. And here is the [service notes](https://www.synthxl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Boss-DSD-2-3-Service-Note.pdf).

Comment: And if all else fails, [try this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mIwTWGOMY0).

Comment: Seems like it's not an option. But be more specific - is it not turning on, not turning off, a control not functioning, no sound, etc?

Comment: Did you actually get a vintage DSD-2 pedal from 1985-1986 as a present?? :D And now the 36 year old device is hanging? This question might be better suited for the Retro Computing stack exchange. :) What guitar store was this, and what decade?

Comment: To be more specific the pedal allows the guitar to be amplified through it both when engaged and not engaged and the check light comes on when the pedal is engaged. The issue is that no effect can be heard when the check light is on. But thank you all for your help :) and yeah it’s a crazy I got such a retro pedal just this Christmas (2021) and the guitar shop is Tyms Guitars based in Brisbane. :D